# Private static variables: header declaration/.cpp definition versus file scope

Tags: c++, static, private-members

I have a class containing only static methods. The header file declares a number of private static member variables which are defined in the corresponding .cpp, giving a single instance of those variables across all translation units. The header contains no method templates or other implementation.

```
// myclass.h

class MyClass
{
private:
  static bool m_boolean;
  static int m_int;
  ...
}

// myclass.cpp

#include "myclass.h"

bool MyClass::m_boolean(false);
int MyClass::m_int(-1);
...
```

What is the reason for declaring private static variables in the header and defining them in the .cpp? It seems can simply move them to file scope in the .cpp with the same storage class:

```
// myclass.h - no private static member variables!

// myclass.cpp

#include "myclass.h"

static bool m_boolean(false);
static int m_int(-1);
...
```

Moving private variables to the .cpp has the added benefit of improving build times by reducing header churn.

The drawback in declaring variables in file scope seems to be that it would open them up to modification by any function in the .cpp, even functions declared in some other class (not that the .cpp contains implementation from other classes in this case). Conversely, declaring in the header/defining in the .cpp restricts variable modification to the declaring class.

Are there any other implications in moving private static class variables to file scope?

Comment: The are private so only the class can modify them?  If you made them globals then anything in the cpp file could access them.

Comment: File scoped variables are considered harmful.

Comment: @KyleHuff considered by whom?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. I do not see a need for the class at all, to begin with.

Comment: The class sounds more like a namespace to me. Just somewhere to put a family of functions. And the static variables are really just globals that are playing hard to get. Are you sure this wouldn't be cleaner implemented as a singleton?

Comment: This smells like bad design to begin with. That being said, you can put your globals in file scope inside an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) (a better wording would be "unique random namespace"), which makes them visible only to the current translation unit.

Comment: @Tim Randall: I think you've hit the nail on the head - it ought to be a singleton. The code was originally migrated from C which partly explains the awkward structure.